# Silverlight datagrids not displaying for certain clients but works fine for others

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, windows-server-2008

I have a website that uses silverlight 4 with datagrids and data charts. The site has been up and running for nearly a year or so but for some reason since last week the silverlight site works only partially for SOME clients/customers but works fine for other clients/customers.

On my local development environment everything works fine as required but when deploy to the live server the website shows all parts of the silverlight site except for the datagrids (they do not not show up at all).
For example, at the top of the silverlight page there are multiple charts which will always display fine on all computers/browsers but just below this there are roughly 10 datagrids that only display for certain computers/browsers/customers. I have made no changes to the site itself before this became an issue. The site is hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2  VPS (though the hosting company may have done some maintenance that I am not aware of).
Both the datacharts and datagrids use the same web service to retrieve and display information.

Are there any recent updates to silverlight 4 or Windows Server 2008 R2 that may be the cause of this? If not, are there any obvious things to investigate to find the root cause of the problem? I am pretty stumped as to even where to begin investigating this issue.

No exceptions are generated nor do I have any event logs relating to the issue. Also, I have written many many silverlight 4 apps & sites and have never experienced this problem until last week. The big question is why would this problem only appear on certain computers (on all browsers on the computer) but not other computers?

It is definitely not a data-related issue because I have an exact backup of the live server in my local development/test environment where it works fine.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Kind Regards

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have managed to figure out the problem and just in case anyone else is experiencing the same type of issue, it is luckily quite simple to resolve. After 5 solid days of bug hunting we found that all you need to do is to make sure that your Adobe Flashplayer (yes you read right) is updated to the latest version! It seems that the ActiveX controls used by both flash and by silverlight that were/are installed on our clients' computers were outdated and vulnerable. Silverlight will not notify you of any new updates to install (since there arent any) but when you try to open up a flash page that uses the latest flash player api it will let you know that there is a new version out which in turn contains updated ActiveX controls which in turn fix the problem we had.

You can explicitly force a Flash update by going into your control panel and in there you will find an item named 'Flash' which opens up the flash configuration. Go to the advanced settings tab where there is a button 'Check Now' to check and update your flashplayer and ActiveX components to the latest version...once this is done, your silverlight app will work 100% as before.

Hope this saves someone some time and effort in the future.

Regards
Leon Botha